# Duplicate a Java Hashtable

Tags: java, hashtable, duplicates

I have a question about duplicate Hashtables in Java (maybe duplicate Java Collections).

My Hashtable have pairs like this:

- Key: String
- Value: Objects of type `C`

`C` looks like this:

```
public interface A extends Cloneable, Serializable{...}

public abstract class B implements A{...}

public class C extends B{...}
```

I want to copy this hashtable in another variable with the same content by using `new Hashtable(Map t)`.
My question is: Which are the conditions for the value objects to make this operation? Can I use the Hashtable copy constructor for this?

I can use `SerializationUtils.clone` for the values, but it takes too long to execute.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Excuse me but I have to edit my question. I think your answers are still right... Thanks everyone

Comment: Using clone will give you the same type of Map back. Using the constructor says, I don't care what type the Map was, it will be a Hashtable now.  IMHO don't use Hashtable or vector as these were replaced in Java 1.2 (1998) unless you have to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your C class or one of its interfaces also supplies a public `.clone()` method (and this really does what you want for single `C` objects), a simple way without serialization would be this (using HashMap instead of Hashtable, but it does not really matter here):

```
/**
 * deeply clones a Map by cloning all the values.
 */
public Map<String,C> deepCopy(Map<String, C> original) {
    Map<String, C> copy = new HashMap<String, C>(original.size());
    for(Map.Entry<String, C> entry : original.entries()) {
        copy.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().clone());
    }
}
```

Comment: I have solved this issue. I have made a deep copy like this sample. If I have implemented my own classes and I know how they are, this way is better than _Serialization.clone()_. Thank you Paulo

Answer (score 7):

If you don't need a deep copy, then using [`new Hashtable(Map t)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#Hashtable%28java.util.Map%29) should work just fine.

[`SerializationUtils.clone()`](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.3/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html#clone%28java.io.Serializable%29) serializes and de-serializes the entire object-graph referenced by the `Map`, that's why it takes so long. It creates a true deep-copy, however (provided you don't have funny serialization-stuff going on in your classes).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and excuse me for my poor english. I think I need a deep copy, because I need to modify copied values in the copied Hashtable. So, I must retain original table, take one copy and work with the copy without modify the original one. Should the constructor work for me? Thanks again

Comment: @yaki_nuka: no, given those requirements that will not work. You could try to make your `C` class immutable, this way you could use the constructor. If you need to modify a `C` object then you could just make the modification method return a new copy of that object with the modification applies (see [`BigInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) for an example of that pattern).

Comment: I have to edit my question, but your answer is still valid, isn't it? Deep copy is required for me. Thanks.

Comment: Oh I see I got -1 for not knowing the almighty `org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils` library :)

Comment: @t-edd: your answer got a -1, because it added nothing new to the question. It's not an attack at you.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer,can you provide me with a working example for this issue.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer,i need a working example for above problem :Duplicate a Hashtable.can you provide me with a working java example which simulates that we can create 2 duplicate hashtable's

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new Hashtable(Map t)`, just be aware that the second Hashtable will contain the same instances as the first one (not copies of the objects)...

And by the way you should consider using HashMap rather then Hashtable, Hashtable is an older class that is synchronized where HashMap is the unsynchronized equivalent, the other difference is that HashMap also permits null...